# How to check EOF condition when using istream::ignore() function?

Tags: c++

My test file contains just 2 characters: `a` and `\n`:

```
$ hexdump -C a.txt
00000000  61 0a                                             |a.|
00000002
```

I want to test [istream::ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) function:

(1) I use `ifs.ignore(2)` to skip `a` and `\n`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("a.txt");

    while (!ifs.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "Not end of file\n";
        ifs.ignore(2);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Test result is like this:

```
$ ./a.out
Not end of file
```

Program only enter loop once, and it fits my expectation.

(2) I use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'` to skip `a` and `\n`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("a.txt");

    while (!ifs.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "Not end of file\n";
        ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

But this time the program enters loop 2 time:

```
$ ./a.out
Not end of file
Not end of file
```

I can't understand this. Per my understanding:

```
ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

should pass all characters, and `ifs.eof()` should return `true` the second time.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) will only set `eofbit` if it encounters the end of the stream. In your case, it instead encounters the `\n`, discards this, then returns *without examining the stream further*. It has therefore not encountered the end of the stream in the first iteration, since it stops inspecting after extracting `delim`; for all it knows, there could be more data after the `\n`, because it hasn't tried to look at it yet.

Comment: So in first case(`ifs.ignore(2)`), `ifs` will set `eofbit` after ignoring `2` chars. Right? Thx!